# React Native IOS/ Expo build failing for multiple reasons

Tags: ios, node.js, typescript, react-native, expo

A expo build is failing on my computer though it is working on the other developers' laptop. The discrepancies are that he is running another version of IOS on his simulator, we don't see this being the issue though.

Problem:
After an `expo start -c` & running on IOS the build fails with the following errors:

````
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:95:17 in reportException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:141:19 in handleException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:39 in handleError
at node_modules/@react-native/polyfills/error-guard.js:49:36 in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError
at node_modules/metro-runtime/src/polyfills/require.js:237:40 in guardedLoadModule
at http://192.168.0.62:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:null in global code

Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 11): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient, RCTEventEmitter.
        A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:95:17 in reportException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:141:19 in handleException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:39 in handleError
at node_modules/@react-native/polyfills/error-guard.js:49:36 in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError

Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 11): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient, RCTEventEmitter.
        A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:95:17 in reportException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:141:19 in handleException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:39 in handleError
at node_modules/@react-native/polyfills/error-guard.js:49:36 in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError```

Has anyone seen this or does anyone have ideas on how to get around this issue?

I have tried npm install, clearing caches, resetting file paths, and rebuilding expo builds.
````

Comment: i have similar problem. app working on iphone but not on android with ReferenceError: Can't find variable: BigInt ... at node_modules/metro-runtime/src/polyfills/require.js:237:40 in guardedLoadModule

Comment: @nelm We found out that it was because of A library we were using in react (Carousel Library) that didnt work with expo, once we replaced that it started working, somewhere in the logs you may be able to find which Library is causing the error

Comment: found that solana/web3.js no longer compatible with latest expo.  trying togo around by building react native with expo older version and keep expo dep minimum as possible